# Amplify configure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have installed 'amplify-cli'. When I type 'amplify configure', I get the error message:

'amplify is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'.

Comment: Some additional info would be appreciated, just so others finding this question can make use of it. Did you encounter any error while running `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`? What platform this your this on?

Comment: Yes, I encountered  error while installing cordova using the android platform. It was resolved when I used 'npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please share your platform. Are you developing on Linux, Windows (Powershell), or Linux on Windows (WSL/Ubuntu)?

Did you install the CLI globally?

Try this:

`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

And see if that works. If the global install fails, you can try running this [per an Amplify developer](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1996#issuecomment-519625952):

`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true`

Edit: since you're on Windows, it's possible the CLI wasn't added to your $PATH variable. You can fix it by seeing [this Github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/13#issuecomment-465667179).

Comment: I have installed CLI globally. My platform is Windows.

Comment: I used the code that you suggested  (npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, simply edit a PATH key under system Environment Variables and add a new path pointing to amplify:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\amplify.cmd
```

If you have globally installed amplify/cli then you should find two files named amplify and amplify.cmd in the above mentioned npm directory.

Comment: I tried your solution @Balogun Ridwan Ridbay but it still doesn't work

Comment: Adding C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\amplify.ps1 to PATH is also needed

Answer (score 1):

Under same circumstances I run all the suggested solutions on Windows 10 machine (64 bit). None of them seemed to do the trick.
I got a more specific error:

> ..... cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
> system ....     + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [],
> PSSecurityException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

The issue appears due to Windows PowerShell execution policies. Eventually, I managed to amend it by applying the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32>powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions didn't work for me, I had to run this instead of 'amplify init':

C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\amplify init

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my problem was because I was trying to install it using

```
yarn global add @aws-amplify/cli
```

Apparently, it doesn't work when it is installed with `yarn` it has to be `npm`. It's funny because there are no errors shown. There might be a fix to it maybe someone can look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows platform avoid using the **global(-g)** flag from your npm command. Install Amplify CLI with below npm command.

```
npm install @aws-amplify/cli
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Error:

amplify : The term 'amplify' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.                                                                                           le program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- amplify init

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (amplify:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

***Try this for windows:***

**Step 1:**

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

**Step 2:**

```
npm config get prefix
```

**Step 3:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

you must run this code on **PowerShell** not a cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
For Windows, try the below command to install Amplify CLI

> $ curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o
> install.cmd && install.cmd
>
> $ amplify configure

for more info on installation follow the link
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install/

Answer (score 0):

Mine only worked when I added "C:\Users\nameoftheuser\AppData\Roaming\npm" to Path user variables in Environmnet variables manager.