# AWS Amplify configure not allowing sign-in to console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli

I am attempting to configure my AWS Amplify app, and am running into an error using `amplify configure`.

After properly installing and configuring the AWS/CLI, and installing the `aws-amplify/cli` module as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513948/amplify-configure), I attempted using the `amplify configure` command as per [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM0iisnRYUk). However, I am met with the following error (assume 'user' is my valid username):

```
C:\Users\user\project>amplify configure
Follow these steps to set up access to your AWS account:

Sign in to your AWS administrator account:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/
Press Enter to continue
2020-02-16T02:12:08.705Z - error: uncaughtException: spawn cmd ENOENT date=Sat Feb 15 2020 18:12:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), pid=1820, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=C:\Users\user\CMAA, execPath=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v12.16.0, 
argv=[C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\bin\amplify, configure], rss=253734912, heapTotal=211009536, heapUsed=180695704, external=13705474, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=232949, trace=[column=19, 
file=internal/child_process.js, function=Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit, line=267, method=onexit, native=false, column=16, 
file=internal/child_process.js, function=onErrorNT, line=469, method=null, native=false, column=21, 
file=internal/process/task_queues.js, function=processTicksAndRejections, line=84, method=null, native=false], stack=[Error: spawn cmd ENOENT,     

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19),     
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16),     
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)]
```

I've tried deciphering this,but I can't find `child_process.js`, which makes me think that it's just some child process, however that gives me even less clue on fixing it.

There is no difference in behavior between Node.js Command Prompt and Windows Powershell

Has anybody else encountered a problem like this, and how did you fix it?

Also let me know if this question needs to be moved to SuperUser, I just put it here after I found the aforementioned answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include `cmd.exe` in your %PATH% variable. Had me stuck, and that's all it was